# changing bases/rotating axes to find reflection across y=2x

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find the (exact) reflection of the vector v = (5, 1) across the line: y = 2x.
Hint: A sketch of v and the line may suggest an approach.

I found the matrix
-3/5 6/5
4/5 2/5
which seems like it gives the reflection across y=2x

But my question is: is there way to do this by rotating the axes and changing bases? (I'm pretty sure this is what the assignment is asking me to do)
I'm having a hard time visualizing it since no angle is given to put into the rotation equations for R2
i.e.

x'=xcosθ +ysinθ

y'=-xsinθ+ycosθ

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

The matrix
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} $$
is clearly a reflection in the $x$-axis. Therefore what we want to do is map $y=2x$ to the $x$-axis with a rotation, reflect, and then undo the rotation. Suppose our line has angle $\tan{\theta}$ to the $x$-axis (here, $\tan{\theta}=2$, from which we can find cosine and sine using $\cos^2+\sin^2=1$ and $\cos^2 = 1/(1+\tan^2)$, as $\cos{\theta}=1/\sqrt{5}$, $\sin{\theta}=2/\sqrt{5}$ ). Then a rotation that sends $y\cos{\theta}=x\sin{\theta}$ to $x=0$ is
$$ \begin{pmatrix} \cos{\theta} & \sin{\theta} \\ -\sin{\theta} & \cos{\theta} \end{pmatrix}. $$
Then the whole reflection is given by
$$ \begin{pmatrix} \cos{\theta} & -\sin{\theta} \\ \sin{\theta} & \cos{\theta} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \cos{\theta} & \sin{\theta} \\ -\sin{\theta} & \cos{\theta} \end{pmatrix}, $$
which when you multiply out and simplify gives
$$ \begin{pmatrix} \cos{2\theta} & \sin{2\theta} \\ \sin{2\theta} & -\cos{2\theta} \end{pmatrix} $$
Putting $\theta=\arctan{2}$ and re-expanding should give
$$ \begin{pmatrix} -3/5 & 4/5 \\ 4/5 & 3/5 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: thanks man, is there any particular way you figured out that third matrix?

Comment: The third matrix?

Comment: "Then a rotation that sends ycosθ=xsinθ to x=0 is:" sorry I haven't learned how to format properly on this site yet

Comment: Ah, well, you can look at what it does to the line and its normal: one is sent to $(1,0)$, the other to $(0,1)$. It is then easy to solve the equations to find the correct matrix. (And you have listed the rotation matrix in your question, so I assumed you knew how that worked.)

Comment: @fattycakez That *second* matrix is a common matrix that I guess you should know